# How to open conemu from freecommander dos command button?

Tags: conemu, freecommander

How to open new tab in ConEmu from FreeCommander dos-prompt command button in toolbar, open active directory from one of the panels in new ConEmu tab? It opens cmd.exe every time, I have option checked for forcing ConEmu as default terminal...

[I want this in FreeCommander](http://tinyurl.com/o45zh4z)

Comment: What are you doing and what you have configured?

Comment: How can I show you my whole configuration in ConEmu? Send you ConEmu.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

ConEmu64 /dir "%ActivDir%" /run cmd.exe /k CmdInit.cmd

Add these to your path and confirm path refreshed before trying. 
C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu
C:\Program Files\ConEmu

Answer (score 0):

"-Reuse" argument is what you need. Go to "Tools/Settings" and there go to "View/DOS Prompt". Type this in "DOS box command specification": "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe -Reuse". Make sure your math to ConEmu executable is correct. Here's the link to see all other options available. https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html